# How i can extend a function from Woocommerce Product Bundle plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-plugin-creation

I want to Extend a function(method) from Woocommerce Product Bundle and modify it in my custom plugin.

```
class WC_Bundled_Item {

/**
 * Bundled item settings meta are copied from the low-level data object to this array - @see WC_Bundled_Item::load_data().
 * @var array
 */
public $item_data = array();

/**
 * A reference to the bundled item data object - @see WC_Bundled_Item_Data.
 * @var WC_Bundled_Item_Data
 */
public $data = null;

/**
 * Product instance of the associated bundled product.
 * @var WC_Product
 */
public $product;

/**
 * Product instance of the parent Bundle.
 * @var WC_Product_Bundle
 */
private $bundle;

/**
 * The title of the bundled item.
 * @var string
 */
private $title;


/**
 * Optional status of the bundled item.
 * @var string
 */
private $optional;



/**
 * __construct method.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $bundled_item_id
 * @param  mixed  $parent
 */
public function __construct( $bundled_item, $parent = false ) {

    if ( is_numeric( $bundled_item ) ) {
        $this->data = WC_PB_DB::get_bundled_item( absint( $bundled_item ) );
    } elseif ( $bundled_item instanceof WC_Bundled_Item_Data ) {
        $this->data = $bundled_item;
    }

    if ( is_object( $this->data ) ) {

        if ( is_object( $parent ) && $this->get_bundle_id() === $parent->get_id() ) {
            $this->bundle = $parent;
        }

        $this->load_data();

        /**
         * 'woocommerce_before_init_bundled_item' action.
         *
         * @param  WC_Bundled_Item  $this
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_before_init_bundled_item', $this );

        $bundled_product = wc_get_product( $this->get_product_id() );

        // if not present, item cannot be purchased.
        if ( $bundled_product && $bundled_product->is_type( array( 'simple', 'variable', 'subscription', 'variable-subscription' ) ) ) {

            $this->product     = $bundled_product;
            $this->title       = 'yes' === $this->override_title ? $this->title : $bundled_product->get_title();
            $this->description = 'yes' === $this->override_description ? $this->description : $bundled_product->get_short_description();

            if ( false !== $parent && $this->is_purchasable() && $this->is_priced_individually() ) {
                $this->sync_prices();
            }
        }

        /**
         * 'woocommerce_after_init_bundled_item' action.
         *
         * @param  WC_Bundled_Item  $this
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_after_init_bundled_item', $this );
    }
}
/**
 * Optional item.
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
public function is_optional() {
    
    return 'yes' === $this->optional;
    
}
```

The last function is_optional() ,i need to change.This is the custom plugin,I have tried:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: My custom Plugin
 * Description: Custom modifications for WC_Bundled_Item class.
 * Version: 1.0
 * Author: 
 */

// Exit if accessed directly.
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

// Get the base directory path of the plugins folder
$plugins_dir = WP_PLUGIN_DIR;

// Specify the relative path to the file you want to include
$plugin_file = $plugins_dir . '/woocommerce-product-bundles---18.1/includes/class-wc-bundled-item.php';

// Include the WC_Bundled_Item class file
require_once $plugin_file;


// Create a custom plugin and define your custom class
class SP_WC_Bundled_Item extends WC_Bundled_Item {

    /**
     * Override the function and modify its value.
     */
    public function is_optional() {
        // Modify the function value here
        echo 'Custom function called! New value: ';
        return $this->optional;
    }

    /**
     * Override the constructor and pass the required argument(s).
     */
    public function __construct( $item_data = array() ) {
        parent::__construct( $item_data );
    }
}

// Instantiate your custom class
$rg_bundled_item = new SP_WC_Bundled_Item();

// Call your custom function to retrieve the value
$is_optional = $rg_bundled_item->is_optional();

// Output the result
echo $is_optional;
```

It outputs the *Custom function called! New value:* but,not changing the is_optional() function.

Any Idea how i should implement this,or please share a proper method to do this .Thanks in advance